# "Callable[list, Dict]: has too many arguments in its declaration; expected 2 but 3 argument(s) declared" when using Typeguard runtime type checker

Tags: python, typechecking, callable

### Context

The (typed) `get_next_actions` function below returns a (typed) function, called `actions_0` (or None). The `actions_0` function takes in 3 arguments, and returns a Dict.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Callable, Dict, List
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from some_imports import Script
else:
    Script = object


# pylint: disable=W0613
    @typechecked
    def get_next_actions(
        required_objects: List[Dict[str, str]],
        optional_objects: List[Dict[str, str]],
        script: Script,
    ) -> Union[Callable[[AutomatorDevice, Screen, Script], Dict], None]:
        """Looks at the required objects and optional objects and determines
        which actions to take next.
        An example of the next actions could be the following List:
        0. Select a textbox.
        1. Send some data to a textbox.
        2. Click on the/a "Next" button.

        Then the app goes to the next screen and waits a pre-determined
        amount, and optionally retries a pre-determined amount of attempts.
        """
        # In the start screen just press ok.
        return actions_0

    return Screen(
        get_next_actions=get_next_actions,
        is_start=True,
        max_retries=max_retries,
        screen_nr=screen_nr,
        wait_time_sec=wait_time_sec,
        required_objects=required_objects,
    )


# pylint: disable=W0613
@typechecked
def actions_0(dev: AutomatorDevice, screen: Screen, script: Script) -> Dict:
    """Performs the actions in option 1 in this screen.

    For this screen, it clicks the "OK" button in the "Connection
    request".
    """
    # Click the ok button.
    dev(resourceId="android:id/button1").click()

    # Return the expected screens, using get_expected_screen_nrs.
    action_nr: int = int(inspect.stack()[0][3][8:])
    screen_nr: int = screen.screen_nr
    script_flow: nx.DiGraph = script.script_graph
    return {
        "expected_screens": get_expected_screen_nrs(
            G=script_flow, screen_nr=screen_nr, action_nr=action_nr
        )
    }
```

### Error Message

However, [Typeguard typechecking](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does not agree with specifying 3 input types into the function.

```
TypeCheckError: the return value (function) did not match any element in the union:
  Callable[list, Dict]: has too many arguments in its declaration; expected 2 but 3 argument(s) declared
  NoneType: is not an instance of NoneType
```

When I change:

```py
) -> Union[Callable[[AutomatorDevice, Screen, Script], Dict], None]:
```

to:

```py
) -> Union[Callable[[AutomatorDevice, float, Script], Dict], None]:
```

the bug dissapears.

### Question

How can I ensure typechecking understands it is the typing of the `action_0` function that is passed into the `callable` type?

### MWE

````py
```py
"""MWE."""

import inspect
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Callable, Dict, List

import networkx as nx
from typeguard import typechecked
from uiautomator import AutomatorDevice

from some_imports import Screen

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from some_imports import Script
else:
    Script = object


# pylint: disable=W0613
@typechecked
def get_next_actions(
    required_objects: List[Dict[str, str]],
    optional_objects: List[Dict[str, str]],
    script: float,
) -> Callable[[AutomatorDevice, Screen, Script], Dict]:
    """Looks at the required objects and optional objects and determines
    which actions to take next.
    An example of the next actions could be the following List:
    0. Select a textbox.
    1. Send some data to a textbox.
    2. Click on the/a "Next" button.

    Then the app goes to the next screen and waits a pre-determined
    amount, and optionally retries a pre-determined amount of attempts.
    """
    # In the start screen just press ok.
    return actions_0


# pylint: disable=W0613
@typechecked
def actions_0(dev: AutomatorDevice, screen: Screen, script: Script) -> Dict:
    """Performs the actions in option 1 in this screen.

    For this screen, it clicks the "OK" button in the "Connection
    request".
    """
    # Click the ok button.
    dev(resourceId="android:id/button1").click()

    # Return the expected screens, using get_expected_screen_nrs.
    action_nr: int = int(inspect.stack()[0][3][8:])
    screen_nr: int = screen.screen_nr
    script_flow: nx.DiGraph = nx.DiGraph()
    return {
        "expected_screens": get_expected_screen_nrs(
            G=script_flow, screen_nr=screen_nr, action_nr=action_nr
        )
    }


@typechecked
def get_expected_screen_nrs(
    G: nx.DiGraph, screen_nr: int, action_nr: int
) -> List[int]:
    """Returns the expected screens per screen per action."""
    expected_screens: List[int] = []
    for edge in G.edges:
        if edge[0] == screen_nr:
            if action_nr in G[edge[0]][edge[1]]["actions"]:
                expected_screens.append(edge[1])
    return expected_screens


required_objects: List[Dict[str, str]] = [{"key": "val_1"}]
optional_objects: List[Dict[str, str]] = [{"key": "val_2"}]
script: float = 9.4

something = get_next_actions(
    required_objects=required_objects,
    optional_objects=optional_objects,
    script=script,
)

print(something)
````

With: `some_imports.py` as:

```py
from typing import Callable, Dict, List, Union
from typeguard import typechecked

class Screen:
    """Represents an Android app screen."""

    # pylint: disable=R0913
    # pylint: disable=W0102
    @typechecked
    def __init__(
        self,
        is_start: bool,
        get_next_actions: Callable[
            [Dict[str, str], Dict[str, str], Dict[str, str]],
            Union[Callable, None],
        ],
        max_retries: int,
        required_objects: List[Dict[str, str]],
        screen_nr: int,
        wait_time_sec: float,
        optional_objects: List[Dict[str, str]] = [],
    ) -> None:
        print("hello world.")


# pylint: disable=R0902
class Script:
    """Experiment manager.

    First prepares the environment for running the experiment, and then
    calls a private method that executes the experiment consisting of 4
    stages.
    """

    # pylint: disable=R0903
    # pylint: disable=R0913
    @typechecked
    def __init__(
        self,
        app_name: str,
        overwrite: bool,
        package_name: str,
        version: str,
        cli_input_data: Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, str]]],
    ) -> None:
        self.app_name: str = app_name
```

Throws error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/git/temp/mwe.py", line 78, in <module>
    something = get_next_actions(
  File "/home/name/git/temp/mwe.py", line 36, in get_next_actions
    return actions_0
  File "/home/name/miniconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard/_functions.py", line 164, in check_return_type
    check_type_internal(retval, annotation, memo)
  File "/home/name/miniconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard/_checkers.py", line 756, in check_type_internal
    checker(value, origin_type, args, memo)
  File "/home/name/miniconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard/_checkers.py", line 193, in check_callable
    raise TypeCheckError(
typeguard.TypeCheckError: the return value (function) has too many arguments in its declaration; expected 2 but 3 argument(s) declared
```

When it is ran with `python mwe.py`

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [mre] that we can run?

Comment: As above, you haven't provided enough code to diagnose the problem (you should at least show where you call actions_0 but an MRE would be better). Also, your pylint disables are at the level of the entire module so there is no need to put them more than once.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have included a MWE that throws a similar error. In the actual code, Thank you for the insight on pylint scope.